# Passing variables from within object into setTimeout

Tags: javascript, architecture

I'm having some interesting issues with passing in variables from within an object into `setTimeout`. At first, I tried putting the function I was calling from `setTimeout` on my object so that I wouldn't have to pass any variables into it (I was hoping it could access my object by itself). That didn't work, apparently because the function somehow became global when I called it from `setTimeout`, and no longer had access to my object's variables.

This was my next attempt, but it doesn't work either:

```
function MyObj() {
    this.foo = 10;
    this.bar = 20;
    this.duration = 1000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        AnotherFunction(this.foo, this.bar)
    }, this.duration);
}
```

So, how exactly can I pass in a variable into `setTimeout` from within an object? No, `AnotherFunction` won't be able to directly access `MyObj` for various unrelated reasons, so that's out of the question too.

Comment: what do you hope to achieve here? what's `AnotherFunction` called for? by convention, constructors start with Capitalized letters. is `AnotherFunction` another constructor? or just a function to be called?

Comment: It's very complex, that's why I didn't copy my actual code in here. Basically, 'for real', it's a function called ClearCharacter that clears an ASCII character off the page by calling another object's Draw() function, which overwrites MyObj's Draw() function, which is another function I didn't include here because it was irrelevant but that draws an ASCII character on the page via setting the innerHTML value of a <p> element. Like I said, complex and very irrelevant. So yeah, `AnotherFunction` is just a function to be called. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that when your function executes, `this` is no longer bound to `MyObj`. You could try

```
function MyObj() {
    var that = this;
    this.foo = 10;
    this.foo = 20;
    this.duration = 1000;

    setTimeout(function(){AnotherFunction(that.foo, that.bar)}, this.duration);
}
```

Or I do have one more idea should that not work.

Comment: @Elliot Cool. Just for completeness, I think your other option would be a closure or IIFE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: IIFE: that's wicked cool. Thanks again! I'll be able to accept your answer in about a minute.

Comment: Confusing as hell when you first see it though!

Comment: Well, it makes a certain degree of sense. I'll never understand *why* it works, though. :P

Comment: I have seen this situation arise a decent amount of times where the `this` operator becomes out of scope in dynamic functions. Adam's approach is the same solution I have seen where a variable holds the pointer to the `this` operator which was intended to be used.

Comment: If you need help considering _why_ it works, consider this (no pun intended): The JS expression `this` is not a variable, it is a special expression whose meaning depends on context.  So for the code in your question, by the time your callback is called `this` means something *different* than it did within `MyObj`.  In Adam's answer, he locked the value of the original object within the variable `that` whose value was the same when the callback ran.  TL;DR: In JS `this` is *not a variable*!!  It's meaning depends on context.

Comment: Good explanations. As for the importance of context, consider also if you called `setTimeout` from inside a loop `for(i=0...` and used `i` instead of `that.foo`. It's likely that by the time the function gets called, `i` will have been incremented in the background, and all references in each of the functions would point to the same `i`.